# Changing order of integration of $\int_0^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty} f_{Y}(x) dx\ dy $?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to follow a proof where $Y$ is a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_{Y}$.

What I don't get is how or why changing order of integration of the following

1. $\int_0^{\infty} P(Y \gt a) dy = \int_0^{\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty} f_{Y}(x) dx\ dy $       **leads to**
2. $ = \int_0^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{x}\ dy) f_{Y}(x)\ dx$

What are the explicit algebraic or calculus manipulations which take us from 1 to 2?

Comment: They are applying Fubini's theorem. What exactly do you want to know? I am not really understanding what is your question. Are you having trouble with the integral bounds?

Comment: By the way, there is a little problem with 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} P(Y > a) dy
$$
because $y$ does not appear in the integrand. There is also a problem with $2.$ because there $a$ has disappeared.

Comment: what's the problem? $a$ is just some constant. The integral $\int_0^{\infty}$ just happens to contain the expression $P(Y \gt a)$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I realize they are applying Fubini's theorem, but what is the algebra that takes us from the equation in **1** to the one in **2**?

Comment: The lower bound of the inner integral should be $y$ not $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will guess what would've been the correct expression. I am guessing 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} P(Y > y) dy 
$$
is the integral you want to compute (there is a theorem in which this expression appears...). 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} P(Y > y) dy = \int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} f_Y(x) \, dx \, dy.
$$
Now you want to start integrating this integral with respect to $y$ instead of $x$ first. The region of the $xy$-plane you are integrating over is 
$$
\{ (x,y) \, | \,0 \le y \le x \}
$$
because $y$ has no constraint except being positive, but $x$ has the constraint of being greater than $y$. If you swap these conditions around, $x$ has no constraint, but $y$ has the constraint of being smaller than $y$. This means that by Fubini's theorem,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} f_Y(x) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^x f_Y(x) \, dy \, dx.
$$
Note that the order of integration has changed, so that since $f_Y(x)$ does not depend on $y$, the first integral can be factored : 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^x f_Y(x) \, dy \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_0^x \, dy \right) f_Y(x) \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} x \, f_Y(x) \, dx = \mathbb E [ Y ],
$$
which I'm guessing was the point of this computation.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes that helps and you guess correct. The reason I took $a$ to be the place of $y$ was just confusion over application of e.g. $P(Y \le a) = F_y(a) = \int_0^a f_y(a) dy $. Here the proof specifically intends to prove $\mathrm{E}[Y] = \int_0^{\infty} P(Y > y) dy$

Comment: Did you mean $y$ has the constraint of being smaller than $x$?

Comment: Well essentially if you first integrate over $y$ then over $x$, then $y$ is free and $x \ge y$. But if you integrate first over $x$ and then over $y$, then $x$ is free and $0 \le y \le x$. But of course this is just two different ways of saying that $0 \le y \le x$.